# Need open source for file handling

Tags: java, file, open-source, file-io

There are many file operations in my program, such as copy/move/delete files.

Of course, I could use JDK `java.io.File` class to handle such operations, but I think there are must better open source solution, which is more powerful, more efficient, more convenient and cross-platform, for this case. Could you recommended one? Thanks!

Comment: Why do you think there have to be better open source solutions than what comes with the language?  (Isn't most of Java Open Source by now?)

Comment: @David: because I know many open source in Java world, and file handling is popular in program, so I think there should be open source solutions.

Comment: Most Open Source solutions build on top of java.io.File.  Anything wrong with that?

Comment: @Thorbjørn: nothing wrong with File, just Apache Commons IO Library can do more powerful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can have a look at the [Apache Commons IO Library](http://commons.apache.org/io/).

Answer (score 4):

There's also [Google Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)'s [`Files`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release09/javadoc/com/google/common/io/Files.html)  (from the [`io` package](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release09/javadoc/index.html?com/google/common/io/Files.html)) which

> Provides utility methods for working with files.

You'll find a lot of overlap between Apache Commons IO and `com.google.common.io`. I personally prefer Guava.

Answer (score 2):

[FileUtils](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html) from Apache Commons IO provides quite a few utility methods that would be apt for copying and moving files.